# How to display the current set of links in the webrowser's document field?

Tags: c#

I've created a web browser in windows forms applications VS 2010. I'm trying to make a list view that displays all the set of links that the webpage has.

I tried:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document = this.Browser.Document;
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why would the above code have anything to do with links? Where's your code that gets the links and how do you try to display them?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Your *document* variable has a property *Links* which has all the hyperlinks of the document. You can index into it (*document.Links[0]*) or enumerate it (*foreach(HtmlElement link in d.Links)*) to get individual links and add them to your list view.